# How to insert array to Firebird table field using sql?

Tags: sql, arrays, firebird

I have that table:

```
create table t_place(
  f_plc_timefrom time,
  f_plc_timeto   time,
  f_plc_minute_cost Decimal(18,4)[24]
);
```

So, I can create array field, but I don't know, how can I fill in this array field in SQL code. I tryed to find way in many sources, but I could find nothing. I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is virtually no array support in Firebird in the query and procedural language. As [ain says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048759/466862) there is only some support via the API. Removal of the array functionality is on the table as well. See also [ticket CORE-710](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-710).

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK one can work with arrays only via API, there is no SQL syntax for that.